# Does the second derivative tell me how the variation of the slope of the tangent line to the graph varies?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The first derivative tells me how the slope of the tangent line of each point to the graph varies, while the second derivative tells me how it varies as a true variation?

For example, having $f(x) = x^2$, $f'(x)= 2x$ (therefore the slope of each point of the line tangent to the point is equal to $2x$, for example at the point $x = 1$ is equal to $2$).

While the second derivative tells me how this variation varies, $f ''(x) = 2$. So $f''$ what are you telling me? I don't understand why it's a constant if the slope changes point to point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x)=2x$. It is a straight line with constant slope $2$, and that's what $f'(x)=2$ tells us.

Now consider $f(x)=x^2$. $f'(x)=2x$ tells us that the slope of $f$ is changing at each point, and that change is behaving like the function (straight line) $2x$. Then $f''(x)=2$ is telling us that the variation of the change of $f'$ is constant, which means that the slope of $f$ is changing, but it changes at a constant rate.

And yes, $f''$ does tell you how the slope of $f$ is varying, since the slope is given by $f'$ and the first derivative of $f'$ is $f''$. In an attempt to provide some intuition I'll use the following analogy:

Imagine $f$ as something that given a point $x$ gives you a position for $x$ on the graph. Then $f'$ is telling you how fast or slow a position is changing into the following positions (if $f'$ is positive it is changing upwards, and if $f'$ is negative it is changing downwards). So $f'$ could be though as "the speed" of the position moving. Then $f''$ is telling you how that change varies. If $f''$ is positive and big then $f'$ ("the speed") is going to get bigger rapidly, which means the following positions are going to change faster ($f''$ works as an "acceleration"). If $f''$ is negative then your $f'$ is going to get slower, so the position will change more and more slowly.

Comment: So you are telling me that the slope varies in a ratio of 2?

Comment: What do you mean with "varying in a ratio"?

Comment: why the costant term is 2?

Comment: For $f(x)=x^2$ you have $f'(x)=2x$. Now, for every unit you move (I mean going from $x$ to $x+1$) you get $f'(x+1)=2(x+1)=2x+2=f'(x)+2$, so the slope of the function is bigger by two units. This is what $f''(x)=2$ was saying. Just think that $f'$ is another function, so $f''$ gives you the slope of $f'$. It's like saying $f''$ is the slope of the slope.

Comment: And the slope of slope what are you telling me?

Comment: the f''(x)=2 what's telling me about the f(x)

Comment: $f'$ is the slope of $f$, but you could think of $f'$ as a new function, so $f''$ would be the slope of $f'$ (that's what I meant with "the slope of the slope", but if it is confusing better forget about it). $f''$ is telling you how the function $f'$ is changing, and $f'$ is telling you how $f$ is changing, so $f''$ actually tells you how the change of $f$ is changing.

Comment: In this case f '' (x) = 2 are you telling me that the slope of the tangent line of each point varies by a speed of two? I mean each point is point-2 of the next?

Comment: Yes, The slope at each point will be changing at "a speed of $2$", since at $x$ the slope is $f'(x)$, and at $x+1$ is $f'(x)+2$. But since the slope was talking about how $f$ changes, that's why I said that $f''$ is like the acceleration, because the acceleration tells you how the speed changes (the speed would be $f'$), and the speed tells you how the position changes (the position is $f$).

Comment: If you are running and your distance from the origin is given by $f(x)=x^2$ then your speed at some $x$ would be $f'(x)=2x$ $m/s$, and your acceleration at each point would be $f''(x)=2$ $m/s^2$

Comment: Ok i understand, so the second derivate tell me how is the concavity of the fuction and first derivate tell me if the fuction is increasing and decreasing at point?

Comment: Exactly! That's completely right.

Comment: But the acceleration is the derivate of the velocity, so the acceleration tell me how change the velocity? if the velocity is 2x m/s the acceleration is 2 m/s^2 (why s^2?) because if the x=1 2 m/s, x=2  4 m/s...

Comment: because first we have a plane 0xy where x is the time and y the position, the velocity is s/t of two point (is the slope of the secant line), if we need a velocity at point A for example i must use the derivate for decreasing the point B in such a way is equal to the point A, this is a derivate of s/t, the accelaration is v/t, the acceleration of point A for example is derivate of v/t such a way the point B is equal to the point A. So the acceleration is the derivate of the velocity in the time....wht s^2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115501/discussion-between-darsen-and-markos-andres).

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the 1st derivative tells you the slope of the parent function at any particular point. The 2nd derivative is similar, except it shows the *slope of the 1st derivative* at any point. Let's take the example you used:

If $f(x)=x^2$, then...

$f'(x)=2x$

This is because the slope of $x^2$ at any point is modeled by the function $y=2x$.

Now, if $f'(x)=2x$, then...

$f''(x)=2$

This is because the slope of $2x$ at any point is modeled by the function $y=2$.

**Conclusion:** The equation $f''(x)=2$ indicates that $f'(x)$ increases at a constant rate of 2, which means $f(x)$ is accelerating in the positive direction (since its slope is increasing).